# Odd failure in assert True is True

Tags: python

I am writing some unit tests for some functions I have. This particular one returns a percentage value for the difference between two images. In the test I use the `assert` statement to evaluate a boolean, and it comes out wrong.

The function returns True when the images match within tolerance, and in this run I'm comparing image_a.png with itself, so it returns True every time. For some unknown reason 'assert match is True' is throwing an assertion error every time.

This is the error log:

```
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.5, pytest-4.6.5, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
_____________________________ test_imagediff_match _____________________________

  tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-install2/pytest-5620/test_imagediff_match0')

  def test_imagediff_match(tmpdir):
  """
  Test normal usage of routine. Images are identical and should match with 0 
  error.
  """
  tmpdir.chdir()
  base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  = os.path.join(base_dir, "image_a.png")
  image_b = os.path.join(base_dir, "image_a.png")
  comparison = imagediff.ImageDiff(canon=image_a, export=image_b)
  match = comparison.images_match()
> assert match is True
E assert True is True

pythontools/fluids_testing/tools/tests/test_imagediff.py:20: AssertionError
```

Of course, this should not throw an error.

This error was originally thrown by pytest-4.6.5 on python 2.7.5 in TFS's automated build environment, but I duplicated the error in Python 3.7.4 running in PowerShell.

Does anybody have any idea why logic is failing completely? I originally thought that True had been reassigned, but that's impossible in Python 3.

Comment: Where are you getting this tool from? Search is failing me. My assumption is that they made some weird internal version of `True` that shares a `repr`/`str` form (maybe just the string `"True"`?), but has a different type; you might try doing `print(type(match), repr(match))` to see what it thinks the type is.

Comment: What does the assertion look like? I suspect that one of the `True`s might be `"True"`, or something like that.

Comment: Comparing to `True`, especially with `is` is a code smell IMO. There are only a few cases when it's the right thing to do. This is not one of them.

Comment: @Beefster: I mean, it's better than comparing with `== True` (which is true for `1`, `1.0`, etc.); if you really care about it being *actually* `True`, you should use `is` since `True` is a guaranteed singleton (just like comparing to `None`). It's just that you almost never want to distinguish `True` from "truthy" values, and should just test `assert match` rather than comparing it to anything.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I made the tool myself, but mostly following this tutorial [link](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_ssim.html) except I use PIL for image handling instead of openCV.
`skimage.mesasure.compare_ssim()` returns a float, which I compare with another float that generates the boolean that gets returned.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the only case where you actually want to be sure a value is specifically True is for type-aware formatting (perhaps if each type is colored differently), but you are indeed correct that `==` is worse... Meanwhile for the C codebase at work, the coding style requires us to compare to true/false, which is *definitely* a code smell in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this error before I posted the question by changing the statement to `assert match`, I just wanted to know why this was happening.

And I found the error! imagediff is returning type `numpy.bool_`, which for some reason is not `True`.

```
>>> test.test_imagediff_closematch(pathlib.Path("."))
Type of 'match': <class 'numpy.bool_'>
repr(match) = True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mrea\Documents\FluidsTestTools\pythontools\fluids_testing\tools\tests\test_imagediffssim.py", line 40, in test_imagediff_closematch
    assert match is True
AssertionError
>>>
```

I find it quite odd that `numpy.bool_` doesn't compare to regular `bool`, but I suppose I was comparing them wrong anyway.

Comment: `is` is an *identity* comparison; `numpy.bool_(True) == True` is true, but it isn't the *same* object; `x is True` is true *only* for the one and only singleton object, `True`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ahhh I see. I understand now, one for being equal, one for being the same object. Or for being two different references to the same memory location, like in Java? Thank you!